# Find a regex call in R to return first and last name or full team name only

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to clean a column by retaining only first and last names (or full team name: ex "New England Patriots".

Here is a set of names with differing styles that need to be matched. I need a capture group around the first and last name together or full team name:

```
Matt Schaub QB - ATL    
Phillip Andersen K
Cleveland Browns DEF    
San Francisco 49ers DEF
New England Patriots DEF
J.T. Barrett QB - PIT
Tre McBride WR
N'Keal Harry WR - NE
MyCole Pruitt TE - TEN
J.J. Arcega-Whiteside WR - PHI
Tre'Quan Smith WR - NO
```

This is as far as I got in a regex engine before I started getting lost. Not even sure how close it even was:

```
[A-Z](\\.|[a-z]+)([A-Z]|\\s)
```

Comment: What defines where the name/team name ends?

Comment: @NelsonGon ex: "San Francisco 49ers", "Tre McBride"

Comment: `sub("\\s+([A-Z]{2,}.*|[A-Z]$)",'',your_text)` will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution which might work here:

```
input <- c("Matt Schaub QB - ATL", "Phillip Andersen K", "Cleveland Browns DEF",
           "San Francisco 49ers DEF", "New England Patriots DEF", "J.T. Barrett QB - PIT",
           "Tre McBride WR", "N'Keal Harry WR - NE", "MyCole Pruitt TE - TEN",
           "J.J. Arcega-Whiteside WR - PHI", "Tre'Quan Smith WR - NO")
output <- sub("\\s*\\b[A-Z]+(?: - [A-Z]+)?$", "", input)
output

 [1] "Matt Schaub"           "Phillip Andersen"      "Cleveland Browns"     
 [4] "San Francisco 49ers"   "New England Patriots"  "J.T. Barrett"         
 [7] "Tre McBride"           "N'Keal Harry"          "MyCole Pruitt"        
[10] "J.J. Arcega-Whiteside" "Tre'Quan Smith"
```

The idea here is to remove the initial or initials which occur at the ends of the sport team names.

Comment: This is so close! Only issue is the team names. Ex I'm getting "San 49ers" when I want San Francisco 49ers"

Comment: `by retaining only first and last names` ... please show the output you expect.

Comment: That's where team names make this tricky as they are tech considered a "player" for this df. Looking at your output above [5] should read "New England Patriots" as well as [4] should be "San Francisco 49ers" - some teams have three pieces to their names - others, like [3] Cleveland Browns only have two

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have two different possible patterns, We'll use the package *unglue* to test them both and use the first that matches. (using Tim's data).

```
library(unglue)
patterns <- c(
  "{team_name} {=[A-Z]+} - {=[A-Z]+}", 
  "{team_name} {=[A-Z]+}")

unglue::unglue_vec(input, patterns)
#>  [1] "Matt Schaub"           "Phillip Andersen"      "Cleveland Browns"     
#>  [4] "San Francisco 49ers"   "New England Patriots"  "J.T. Barrett"         
#>  [7] "Tre McBride"           "N'Keal Harry"          "MyCole Pruitt"        
#> [10] "J.J. Arcega-Whiteside" "Tre'Quan Smith"
```